# Where is boto3 credentials file in windows located at by default?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I just installed boto3 in my windows machine using

```
pip install boto3
```

through cmd prompt.
I'm following steps from [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html#configuration) and not able to find the *credentials* file or *config* file mentioned in those steps.

Any advise please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The credentials are located under:

`C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\credentials`

Just follow [AWSCLI setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) guide: